# Send/Receive data using Sockets functions

Tags: php, sockets, port

How can I send data from a PHP page to a TCP Port ?

```
<?php 
// parameters to connect to server
$ip = "192.168.1.3";
$port = "59995";
$data = "Hello";
$output = "";

// Create a TCP Stream Socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Connect to the server.
$result = socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port);

// Write to socket!
socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));

// Read from server
do 
{
  $line =@socket_read($socket,2048);
  echo $line. "\n";
} 
while ($data != "0");

// Close and return.
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I'm using it, but I cant recive any data! Also, do you know how I could make a timeout for this?

What is the problem?

Comment: stop suppressing errors (`@`) when you've got trouble. it's like trying to walk against traffic while blindfolded.

Comment: http://christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

Comment: @mkaatman Shheesh I feel old now. Knowledgeable young chap though

Answer (score 0):

Your program works. If it doesn't receive data, it might be the server's fault. Surely, you want

```
while ($line);
```

instead of

```
while ($data != "0");
```

to let it halt if the server has closed the connection.
For a receive timeout (e. g. 7 s), you can use

```
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>7, "usec"=>0));
```